# Is it possible to change the url of a deployed meteor app?

Tags: meteor

If you look at the source of a deployed meteor app, you'll find the following tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/d6ff5aeb2eea4a3df97ea7dbf3a833a4e76cac20.js?meteor_js_resource=true"></script>
```

Is it possible to change the base of that url to be the absolute URL of the app in any way? For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/d6ff5aeb2eea4a3df97ea7dbf3a833a4e76cac20.js?meteor_js_resource=true"></script>
```

It would be awesome if that could be changed in some setting somewhere versus manually changing the files created by `meteor build`.